# What is the recommended approach to read / parse / write a file using Google Data Flow pipeline?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

Google Dataflow pipeline need to be setup for processing a file (read, transform and write) and then writing the output to another file. In short the process is READ > PARSE > TRANSFORM > WRITE. Is it possible to do this in parallel? How do the records be grouped based on the file? For instance: records from input File A-IN.TXT needs to be written to output file A-OUT.TXT. Is there any built-in capability available to support this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache Beam (SDK used by Google Cloud Dataflow) provides many transforms for handling files. For example,

- [TextIO](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.11.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/TextIO.html): Read text files and produce a `PCollction` of text lines.
- [AvroIO](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.11.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/AvroIO.html): Read Avro files and produce a `PCollection` of records.
- [FileIO](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.11.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/FileIO.html): Many useful transforms for reading and writing files.

Dataflow parallizes reading of these files by (1) initial splitting into logic chunks before reading (2) dynamic work rebalancing to handle stragglers while reading.
See [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/deploying-a-pipeline#dynamic-work-rebalancing) for more details regarding dynamic work rebalancing.

`TextIO`, `AvroIO`, etc., currently do not track input files. So probably you'll have to use transforms offered by `FIleIO`  (for example `FileIO.match()` followed by `FileIO.readMatches()`) and read data from a `ParDO` and produce a `PCollection` that contains records along with the file name. These can be written to corresponding files using the [dynamic destination feature offered by `FileIO`](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.11.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/FileIO.html#writeDynamic--).